# Image (with a background image) as link

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a link to a page working correctly when an image is clicked. On this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cvh2013/KEzT3/) you'll see three circular images. When the mouse is hovered over any of them, a background shadow image is rendered. When you click on the 'law firms' image, a short HTML page with some text should be displayed. What happens is that the link to the law firm text is rendered not as the image itself, but as a '>' character - see screenshot below.

Can anyone guide me how to make the image act as the link, please? Also ensuring that the background image continues to be centred over the law firms image when the mouse is hovered over it.

CSS:

```
.center {text-align: center;}

#sfimages {padding:15px;}

#sfimages:hover {
background-image: url(http://ubuntuone.com/1SRrDB8i8cBtpm3Smxaz5r);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:center;     
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
            <td class="center">
                <div id="sfimages"> 
                <a href="http://ubuntuone.com/3JHwAhFuNUCVfq1QOOjBGG">                              >
                <object type="image/svg+xml"
                    data="http://ubuntuone.com/5b5ZUS86nHAffWiOirDwFr">
                    <img src="http://ubuntuone.com/12qOaTGCZYzQtqFJpaGbPV" alt="" />
                </object>
                </a>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="center">
                <div id="sfimages">
                <object type="image/svg+xml"
                    data="http://ubuntuone.com/6tkHm9c2r1eH9PMB9Nr3Ux">
                    <img src="http://ubuntuone.com/54AaqhQUU8npACF2vXzKFp" alt="" />
                </object>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="center">
                <div id="sfimages">
                <object type="image/svg+xml"
                    data="http://ubuntuone.com/7Ur09JXlGVvF2GhXFbLXlx">
                    <img src="http://ubuntuone.com/4CXw05d1dsSf9VhAIPNZf6" alt="" />
                </object>
                </div>
            </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: In the first case you've left a rogue angle bracket in your code.

Comment: On the 6th line of the HTML there's a `>` which is causing the problem, just remove it and it will look fine.

Comment: Remove that <a> tag from your html.

Comment: Those `alt=""` attrs are wrong. They should contain "Law firms" and so on instead of being empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was spare character: 
please check following code (in a comment there is a link to the full code):

```
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td class="center">
            <div id="sfimages"> 
            <a href="http://ubuntuone.com/3JHwAhFuNUCVfq1QOOjBGG">                              
            <object type="image/svg+xml"
                data="http://ubuntuone.com/5b5ZUS86nHAffWiOirDwFr">
                <img src="http://ubuntuone.com/12qOaTGCZYzQtqFJpaGbPV" alt="" />
            </object>
            </a>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="center">
            <div id="sfimages">
            <object type="image/svg+xml"
                data="http://ubuntuone.com/6tkHm9c2r1eH9PMB9Nr3Ux">
                <img src="http://ubuntuone.com/54AaqhQUU8npACF2vXzKFp" alt="" />
            </object>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="center">
            <div id="sfimages">
            <object type="image/svg+xml"
                data="http://ubuntuone.com/7Ur09JXlGVvF2GhXFbLXlx">
                <img src="http://ubuntuone.com/4CXw05d1dsSf9VhAIPNZf6" alt="" />
            </object>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you bluszcz! I have been staring that code too long and couldn't see it. Note to self - use Eclipse for even a basic HTML page so you get the benefit of the syntax highlighting ...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for taking a while, its been a busy day for me and I just had enough time to come back around to your question.  Here is what I recommend.  It looks like the code you are working with is produced from inkscape?  When it runs the source code is a  nuts, especially inside the object area.  But have no fear if you want links. Simply make the following slight adjustments, and you should be on your way with links!

The CSS:

```
.center {
    text-align: center;
}

#sfimages {
padding:15px;
position:relative;
width:380px;
height:273px;
}

#sfimages:hover {
    background-image: url(http://ubuntuone.com/1SRrDB8i8cBtpm3Smxaz5r);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center;     
}

#ext-site {
display:block;
width:380px;
height:273px;
position:absolute;
z-index:9999;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
            <td class="center">
                <div id="sfimages"> 
                <a id="ext-site" href="http://ubuntuone.com/3JHwAhFuNUCVfq1QOOjBGG"></a>                              
                <object type="image/svg+xml"
                    data="http://ubuntuone.com/5b5ZUS86nHAffWiOirDwFr">
                    <img src="http://ubuntuone.com/12qOaTGCZYzQtqFJpaGbPV" alt="" />
                </object>

                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="center">
                <div id="sfimages">
                <object type="image/svg+xml"
                    data="http://ubuntuone.com/6tkHm9c2r1eH9PMB9Nr3Ux">
                    <img src="http://ubuntuone.com/54AaqhQUU8npACF2vXzKFp" alt="" />
                </object>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="center">
                <div id="sfimages">
                <object type="image/svg+xml"
                    data="http://ubuntuone.com/7Ur09JXlGVvF2GhXFbLXlx">
                    <img src="http://ubuntuone.com/4CXw05d1dsSf9VhAIPNZf6" alt="" />
                </object>
                </div>
            </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is classic trick, involving an asbolute positioned anchor link, inside of a relative display block element.  As long as the anchor stretches to the size of it's parent's size, it acts as an invisible button on top of the entire section.

Check out my new [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blackhawx/EB7Kb/)

Comment: Thank you blachawk - I can see that your jsFiddle displays correctly but the short page that should be rendered when you click the link doesn't appear - does it appear for you? The page reads like this: "Law firms are constantly seeking ways to demonstrate their value to their clients. We help you demonstrate a closer understanding of your clients' businesses and the challenges they face, and deliver a truly proactive service"

Comment: since you are dealing with objects, simply add the following as an attribute on each object element - onclick="window.location='URLHERE'; return false;" and remove the anchor link that is wrapping around it.

Comment: I'm being stupid I know (I'm a server-side guy, UI is so not my field) - but cannot see how to do that. Could you possibly update your jsFiddle for me so I can see? In the meantime I will upvote your answer :-)

Comment: read my revision - it includes a full package for you.  If you want to create a 2nd or third link, just copy the pattern I set up so far.  The following code-revision above, makes the first circle act as a link.

Comment: Thank you so much blachawk, that works just fine! Your help and time is much appreciated. Now I am going to read up on 'position:absolute', 'z-index' and the other CSS elements you used so I can learn how they work.

Comment: By the way - yes, I used Inkscape to create the SVG files.

Answer (score 0):

Line 6:

```
<a href="http://ubuntuone.com/3JHwAhFuNUCVfq1QOOjBGG">                              >
```

Remove the extra closing bracket.