# Image as link and an <object> attribute

Tags: html, css

Following on from my questions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15482357/image-with-a-background-image-as-link) StackOverflow thread, I'm trying to use an image as a link. The image is an SVG file and the link is to a simple static HTML page.

In the question I've referred to it was suggested that I add an attribute of `onclick="window.location='URLHERE'; return false;"` to the object. I've tried a number of configurations (putting this in the `<img>` tag, in the `<object>` tag, creating a small Javascript function and placing it in there) but it doesn't work - the link isn't rendered at all.

My jsFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cvh2013/em6qq/). Can anyone please give me a pointer? Please assume that I know very little about Javascript or even HTML for that matter. Thank you.

CSS:

```
.center {text-align: center;}

#sfimages {padding:15px;}

#sfimages:hover {
background-image: url(http://ubuntuone.com/1SRrDB8i8cBtpm3Smxaz5r);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:center;     
}
```

HTML:

```
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td class="center">
            <div id="sfimages">
                <object class="images" type="image/svg+xml"
                    data="http://ubuntuone.com/5b5ZUS86nHAffWiOirDwFr">
                    <img src="http://ubuntuone.com/12qOaTGCZYzQtqFJpaGbPV" alt=""
                        onclick="window.location='http://ubuntuone.com/3JHwAhFuNUCVfq1QOOjBGG'; return false;" />
                </object>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="center">
            <div id="sfimages">
                <object type="image/svg+xml"
                    data="http://ubuntuone.com/6tkHm9c2r1eH9PMB9Nr3Ux">
                    <img src="http://ubuntuone.com/54AaqhQUU8npACF2vXzKFp" alt="" />
                </object>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="center">
            <div id="sfimages">
                <object type="image/svg+xml"
                    data="http://ubuntuone.com/7Ur09JXlGVvF2GhXFbLXlx">
                    <img src="http://ubuntuone.com/4CXw05d1dsSf9VhAIPNZf6" alt="" />
                </object>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What purpose is the <object> serving?

Comment: It's there to serve up the SVG file - perhaps I could do it some other/better way? I'm a real amateur at this. I thought I was required to use <object>. I'm a server-side coder who's having to get into UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you surround the image with link tags, `<a href="YOUR LINK">` and `</a>`?

Comment: Yes that's the conclusion I reached with the help of blachawk - see his answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15482357/image-with-a-background-image-as-link